# WPF : Change Foreground property of Listbox item from codebehind

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have ListBox control in WPF which is filled up by some observable collection of Type:"Bus".

Bus is a class which contains two properties

1. BusName
2. BusType

so based on the bustype the items in this should have either of the two color

for bus type:

1. Sleeper -  Green
2. Non Sleeper - Blue

All this should happen from WPF code behind.

**Does anyone has idea how to do so.. [I am not expert in WPF.. a little detail will be more helpfull.]**

Comment: Why you want to this in code behind it can very easy achieve using trigger in XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do the same through code behind.. we have the following way to achieve this.. I hope this would help you..

```
DataTrigger datatrigger = new DataTrigger();
datatrigger.Binding = new Binding("BusTypeID");
datatrigger.Value = 1;
datatrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Green));
listbox.Triggers.Add(datatrigger);

DataTrigger datatrigger2 = new DataTrigger();
datatrigger2.Binding = new Binding("BusTypeID");
datatrigger2.Value = 2;
datatrigger2.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
listbox.Triggers.Add(datatrigger2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Integer value for BusType
Let Say,
Sleeper  = 1
Non Sleeper = 2

Just add a property in your collection for BusTypeID

> ```
>     <Style.Triggers>
>             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BusTypeID}" Value="1">
>                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
>             </DataTrigger>
>             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BusTypeID}" Value="2">
>                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
>             </DataTrigger>
>
>     </Style.Triggers> </Style >
> ```

Comment: Please can you tell me how this can be achieved using codebehind.